# Save calculated price in database - Rails best practise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that takes in the price and a discount code. When saved, it then calculates the discount price. This all works just fine. However, I don't know which is the Rails way to save the discount price in the database. Do I do it in the model or in the controller?

I currently have this in the model, but I don't know if this is the correct way to do it:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :set_discount_price

  def set_discount_price
    discount_price_calculator = DiscountPriceCalculator.new(price, discount)
    self.discount_price = discount_price_calculator.calculate_discount_price
  end
end
```

Is this the correct way? And if no, then how else am I supposed to do it?

Comment: There's no one correct way to do this. Your way works and it's how many people would do it. Personally, I find AR callbacks in models annoying to work with, so I avoid them whenever possible. Here, I'd calculate this value in a [`Form Object`](https://dev.to/drbragg/rails-design-patterns-form-object-4d47), which would be called from the controller. This works for me, but, again, some people would argue that it is over-engineering and deviating from the rails way. Ultimately, it's your call.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thank you! I didn't know about Form Object, so I'll definitely look into that!

Comment: This implies the “discount price” is the same for every user and discount code. While possible, it seems improbable—it’s more likely this is better modeled as part of order line items.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct way?

No, there are some pretty big problems with that approach.

If you actually want to keep proper records what you want is to setup a separate join model where you record the original price of the product at the time of sale, the discount applied, and the quantity (and often more).

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :orders, through: :line_items
  has_many :discounts
end

# rails g model line_item quantity:integer unit_price:decimal discount:references gross_price:decimal  
class LineITem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :discount # this could aslo be a many to many association
end

class Discount  < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :products, through: :line_items
end
```

This ensures that existing orders will not be altered if the price on a product changes as the prices on the line items table are "frozen".

When you "ring up an order" you're actually tallying up the line items and additional discounts may be applied.

Also its usually a better idea to record the available discounts per product on a seperate table so that you can model stuff like quantity based discounts or combined discounts.

> Do I do it in the model or in the controller?

Thats a very opinionated question but I would say that the answer is *neither*. Placing it in the model means you will have to deal with distributing the responsibilites ("is it the responisbility of Product or Order?") and you're burdoning classes that already have tons of responsibilits with yet more responsibilites. Remember that models already do persistence, querying, assocations, validations, integrations with the route helpers, I18n, etc.

Callbacks also come with a boatload of problems of their own since they are fired *implicitly* instead of *explicitly* and using them for complex problems can be a nightmare when it comes to testing and just in general getting it to happen when actually intended. Models also don't have any actual context when the callbacks are fired.

Controllers are very hard to test and are already the gluecode holding your entire application together. "Fat controllers" is widely accepted to be an anti-pattern.

Instead you can look at patterns such as form objects, service objects, jobs etc. that let you redestribute the responsibilites and keep your code testable.

Comment: Dealing with money is damn complex but fortunately this is a domain where there is no shortage of books and examples. Whatever you do make sure you put aside time to actually research exisiting solutions and if the don't perfectly suit your use case then at least try to learn from what products like Spree do right.